# Qt: QWidget with a child on QGraphicsView/QGraphicsScene not working

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I'm looking to create a view with a base image in the background and draggable widgets over the top.

The setup I have is like so:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget * parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(new QGraphicsScene(nullptr));
    ui->graphicsView->scene()->addWidget(new BackgroundWidget(nullptr));
}
```

This works fine. So does:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget * parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(new QGraphicsScene(nullptr));
    BackgroundWidget * bgWidget = new BackgroundWidget(nullptr);
    new ForegroundWidget(bgWidget);
    ui->graphicsView->scene()->addWidget(bgWidget);
}
```

However, I want to add foreground widgets dynamically, and it doesn't work. What I've noticed is that the following doesn't add the foreground widget at all:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget * parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(new QGraphicsScene(nullptr));
    BackgroundWidget * bgWidget = new BackgroundWidget(nullptr);
    ui->graphicsView->scene()->addWidget(bgWidget);
    new ForegroundWidget(bgWidget);
}
```

And this adds the foreground widget, but doesn't allow for semi-transparency with the background (which is needed for the project):

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget * parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(new QGraphicsScene(nullptr));
    BackgroundWidget * bgWidget = new BackgroundWidget(nullptr);
    ui->graphicsView->scene()->addWidget(bgWidget);
    ui->graphicsView->scene()->addWidget(new ForegroundWidget(nullptr));
}
```

Any ideas as to why adding a child widget after adding the background widget isn't working? If so, any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks.

EDIT: Corrected some silly typing errors in the code blocks.

[image: Image of the problem]

The image is a reduced version of the issue; the widgets are both set to be semi-transparency (alpha at 100 out of 255), yet one widget seems to be above the other. I get this if I add the 'foreground' widget in any way. Below is what I was expecting to get:

[image: Ok version]

As I say, if I add them before attaching to the scene, it works fine, but I need to be able to add to the scene at run time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several memory leak problems in your code.

Depending on `BackgroundWidget` and `ForegroundWidget` implementation, you either want

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget * parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(new QGraphicsScene(nullptr));
    BackgroundWidget * bgWidget = new BackgroundWidget(nullptr);
    ForegroundWidget * fgWidget = new ForegroundWidget(bgWidget);
    ui->graphicsView->scene()->addWidget(fgWidget);
}
```

or

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget * parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(new QGraphicsScene(nullptr));
    BackgroundWidget * bgWidget = new BackgroundWidget(nullptr);
    ForegroundWidget * fgWidget = new ForegroundWidget(nullptr);
    ui->graphicsView->scene()->addWidget(bgWidget);
    ui->graphicsView->scene()->addWidget(fgWidget);
}
```

Complete example:

```
#include <QtGui>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0) : QMainWindow(parent) {
        QGraphicsView *graphicsView = new QGraphicsView;
        setCentralWidget(graphicsView);

        QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene;
        graphicsView->setScene(scene);

        QWidget *fgWidget = new QWidget;
        fgWidget->setStyleSheet("background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 100)");
        fgWidget->setMinimumSize(100, 100);
        fgWidget->setMaximumSize(100, 100);

        QWidget *bgWidget = new QWidget;
        bgWidget->setStyleSheet("background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 100);");
        bgWidget->setMinimumSize(100, 100);
        bgWidget->setMaximumSize(100, 100);
        bgWidget->move(50, 50);

        scene->addWidget(fgWidget);
        scene->addWidget(bgWidget);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWindow mainWindow;
    mainWindow.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

[image]

If you want `fgWidget` to be parent of `bgWidget`:

```
    QWidget *bgWidget = new QWidget(fgWidget);
    ....
    scene->addWidget(fgWidget);
    //scene->addWidget(bgWidget); // don't add it to the scene
```

[image]

Comment: Updated: I made a couple of copy-paste errors in the original post. I have tried what you suggested already - both add the widget, but completely disable the correct rendering of semi-transparency, which is needed for my project.

Comment: You still have memory leaks. If you use `new`, you have to use `delete`, or pass it to `QObject`-derived classes as parent. You cannot just do things like `new ForegroundWidget(bgWidget);`. Also, post a screenshot.

Comment: Ok, the code snippets are simplified. Can we assume that the pointers are held in the class and deleteLater() called on them in the destructor?

Comment: Added some screen shots.

Comment: Added a complete example.

Comment: Huh... your code works fine... I'm going to have to check my widgets to see if whats caused this. It's pointed me in a new direction.

Comment: Ok, it looks like the widgets where being given a background colour when added after the scene was added...for some reason. Setting the background explicitly transparent has fixed it. Thanks muchly for your help!